# can i use the verb "furnish" for kitchen equipment?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-usage, word-request, vocabulary

I know I can say that an apartment is furnished or not, but can I use the word `furnished` with a kitchen?

I am trying to describe a kitchen that is equipped with the necessary tools for cooking and refrigeration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. ["Furnished"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/furnished) means "to supply (a house, room, etc.) with necessary furniture, carpets, appliances, etc." and a kitchen is a room, so it would fit.

Answer (score 1):

While `furnish` is usually used to mean "provide with furniture," it *can* also refer to other needed items. When I say:

> I fully furnished my brand new apartment over the weekend

Few people would suspect that I mean that I only supplied a brand new apartment with furniture, without other appliances.

However, when talking about specific rooms that have a special designation, then "furnished a kitchen" or "furnished a bathroom" can sound quite odd, though not technically incorrect.

In the case of a kitchen I'd say:

> I equipped the kitchen / I got the kitchen equipped

or

> I bought all the necessary appliances for our kitchen

Comment: You should add a mention to the fact that kitchen utilities like the refrigerator, the oven, etc. are usually referred to as appliances. A "furnished" apartment will almost certainly come with the most common appliances, such as the refrigerator and the oven, but furnished apartments may not come with less important appliances, like a microwave or a toaster. For this reason, housing listings will often list appliances separately, even if the advertisement states the property is "fully furnished".

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would say:

> Appliances included

In the context of apartment rentals, this would mean that the apartment has a stove and a refrigerator.

That said, such a short phrase doesn't necessarily eliminate all ambiguity, as is discussed on [this website](http://www.exposix.com/answers/What-does-it-mean-in-real-estate-to-to-include-all-appliances-What-appliances.html).

Getting back to your question, one could also say

> fully furnished kitchen

I would understand this to mean that the kitchen has all appliances, even a microwave.

Comment: I think ***stove*** sounds very "American" and possibly a bit dated. In the UK today we usually cook using ***cookers*** (***in ovens*** and on ***on hobs*** if they're not both part of a single appliance, and/or we're being more specific about the *kind* of cooking).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "stove" is still used in the US; "range" would be more of an outdated term. Good call, though, on pointing out the AmE/BrE usage difference.

Comment: That's funny. Maybe usage varies within the UK in subtle ways I'm not aware of, but I'd be inclined to see ***stove*** as the more dated term here when contrasted with ***range*** (which these days usually means a really expensive lump of cast iron in some swanky "country kitchen", from the likes of [Aga](http://www.agaliving.com/?ad=generic&gclid=CjwKEAjw3sKpBRDJ7rDqzsyuhDASJACZAikiT4RTt888UkE2ZORDaJhm_TO6M8OLDubNczmsCx6-fxoCv1Tw_wcB))

Comment: I think in American stores we see *cooktops*, *ovens* and *ranges (free-standing oven-cooktop combinations)* but once they are installed in the home the part with the burners is always the *stove* and the part  with the door is always the *oven*.

Comment: Those doors on the Aga look tiny. How do you ever get a turkey in there? http://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-1096708-stock-footage-putting-holiday-turkey-into-the-oven.html

Comment: http://www.tillmancompanies.com/wp-content/uploads/old_kitchen_stove2.jpg